# congestion games , price of anarchy

Tags: proof-writing, game-theory

It is known that if we have a congestion game with delay functions de(x)= x , then the price of anarchy for every resource e is not greater than 5/2.

Which is the price of anarchy when the delay functions are de(x)=a*x+b , a,b >=0 instead of de(x)=x ?

Comment: ???????????????

Answer (score 0):

have a look at this: https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~cswamy/courses/co759/agt-material/christodoulouk-atcongstoc.pdf

I hope this helps.